# How can I use an Artificial Neural Network that was trained with 10 parameters to classify an instance with 3 parameters?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I´d like to use any technique of artificial inteligence to classify elements using several parameters. I have used artificial neural networks (ANN) to do it, with good results. My purpose now is to classify objects without using all the inputs parameters I have used to train my network. I mean:

Suppose I have trained my network with 10 parameters. Then, I´d like to test my network only with 3 parameters (different parameters for each instance). Can I do it with some kind of ANN, or is there another systems to do it?

(Numbers are only an example obviously)

I think my question is useful in many cases, because in some cases you may probably have many information from the past (in time), and you´d like to classify objects in the future time (and you cannot probably have enough information).

Comment: Not sure I am completely following. You have a set of `k` features you train your classifier with, and you are trying to classify with `d < k` features. So far so good - but are these `d` features constant? Is it always the same subset of the original `k`? (If no - the question is very useful!!)

Comment: not exactly related to your question but you may want to look at dimensionality reduction techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a **recommender system**. Systems like this are useful when dealing with lot of uncertain(or not known at all) data. There are many materials in web and literature that explains this topic well.

**EDIT:**
Very good explanation is provided by prof. Andrew Ng in https://www.coursera.org/course/ml

Based on comments, here are some guides:
xavier.amatriain.net/PFC/mramirez-recommender.pdf
infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch9.pdf

Comment: is it similar to fuzzy logic?

Comment: A good guide to understand a recommender system is: http://xavier.amatriain.net/PFC/mramirez-recommender.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If number of unknown parameters and ANN size is not huge, then I'd try integrating over unknown parameters. That could be done numerically by sampling random values for unknown parameters several times and averaging corresponding outputs of the network. The problem here is that number of runs of ANN grows exponentially with number of unknown dimensions.
This method should become more accurate if distribution of inputs is known.

Also, having the distribution of inputs, analytical integration becomes an option. It seems like in this case only transfer functions of first layer are affected. So, you'll need to derive a solution for integral:
`Tnew(other inputs)=integral(p(x|other inputs)*T(x,other inputs),x=min_x..max_x)`, where `p` is a conditional distribution for unknown parameters, `T` is a transfer function for the first layer, `Tnew` is a new transfer function for first layer with all parameters known.